# The Icon of MediaItem can not display in Android Wear via MediaBrowserServiceCompat

Tags: android, wear-os, android-auto

I use setIconUri set a online Image URL at MediaDescriptionCompat Builder like this

```
MediaDescriptionCompat.Builder builder = new MediaDescriptionCompat.Builder();
builder.setMediaId(item.getlistId());
builder.setTitle(item.getlistName());
builder.setIconUri(Uri.parse(item.getlistIconM()));
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(BUNDLE_KEY_MEDIA, R.string.title_theme);
```

then the Image of MediaItem display perfect at Android Auto, but not at Android Wear, why ?
and what should I do fixed this issue ?

Comment: What URI are you using? A `https` URI? Local `content://` URI?

Comment: @ianhanniballake It's a http URI , like this api.mymusic.net.tw/mms/singer/245/245s.jpg , thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Wear only loads remote URLs from `https` - if you are using `http` URLs, you should switch to `https`.